# Не ставится иконка на сайт

Tags: css3

я никак не могу понять, почему иконка не вставляется в адресную строку. Указывать полный путь я пробовал.

Вот пример кода:

```
<head>
    <title> Undertale</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\Sublime Text\Сайт\CCS\ccs1.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
```

местоположение картинки:

[image]

Comment: Удалите свой ответ, а вопрос отредактируйте, нажав под вопросом "править".

Comment: А где код использования favicon.ico из HTML1.html?

Comment: @Rootware, на месте, просто его маркдаун съел.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, что вам говорит об этом консоль браузера.

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно, чтоб был формат .ico
Попробуй, через .png

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/путь-к-картинке/favicon.png" type="image/png">
```